# Select post from dropdown and add query args not working

Tags: redirect, forms, get-posts, select

The behavior of the below should be that the user makes a selection on the dropdown box and the page refreshes with a query arg of `editevent=1` and also passes a value of the post ID with the selection chosen. Above the dropdown, it should say

> Post ID: [post ID here]

The problem is with this bit of code:

```
<option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
</option>
```

When I put the ID of the post as the value, it makes the form redirect to the actual post instead of just refreshing the current page. I can't figure out why it's doing that. I have the form set to `action="#"` and there is no reference to the permalink of any URL in the code.

Here is the full snippet:

```
<?php if ($_GET['editevent'] == true) {
    echo 'Post ID: '.$_GET['page_id'];
}
?>
    <form method="GET" action="#">
    <select name="page_id" id="page_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'event', 'season' => '2013-2014');
        $posts = get_posts($args); 
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="editevent" value="true" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your `<select>` to something other than `page_id`.

The *problem* is that `page_id` is already taken (and handled) by WordPress (as query var).

This should do, for example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['editevent']) && true == $_GET['editevent'])
    echo 'Post ID: '.$_GET['my_page_id'];
?>
<form method="GET" action="#">
    <select name="my_page_id" id="my_page_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'season' => '2013-2014',
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args); 
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
            <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="editevent" value="true" />
</form>
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Ugh, I hate when it's something that dumb and I spent an hour trying to figure it out!

Comment: Glad I could help. Some smartass tip for the future: _When something isn't behaving as expected, first of all assume it's working correctly, anyway. Then try to understand_ **why** _it's working correctly - while not doing what you want it to._ Oftentimes you could have spent only a little time trying to find your error in reasoning, if you hadn't been busy trying to find the mistake _on the other side_. ;) Would you mind accepting my answer to give this question some peace?